# Protobuf package declaration

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a proto file with definition of some messages. I declared `package com.myorganization` at the beginning of proto file. For example there is `message A` declaration in that file. If I serialize that message and the receiver of that message have the same definition of `message A` but it resides in different package and in different proto file and probably use different language. Would the receiver deserialize `message A`?

Answer (score 1):

If the two message definitions are the same, then yes, that will work. It's important for the field numbers to match; if the field names are different then that does not actually matter as far as the binary format is concerned.

Comment: Question is actually about whether the package name is part of the message name in protobuf?

Comment: These names are not serialized at all as part of the binary format, and so in  your question above it does not matter what the sender and receiver think the names are. The package name and message name are used to refer to the message types in your code, but not in the actual binary format.

Comment: So only message structure matters?(types and fields numbers) If Having 2 messages with different names even in one proto file, can they be serialized/deserialized using different messages?

Comment: Exactly, only the message structure matters, just the types and field numbers. And yes, you can have two different messages in the same .proto file and serialize a message as one and deserialize it as the other, as long as their message structures are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The one place that it could matter is if that message encapsulated in an `Any` message.  The [serialization of the `Any` message](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#any) is:

> An Any contains an arbitrary serialized message as bytes, along with a URL that acts as a globally unique identifier for and resolves to that message’s type

> The default type URL for a given message type is `type.googleapis.com/_packagename_._messagename_`

As a result, if the reader does not have the same package name then it will not be able to find the appropriate message to decode the `Any` payload.  I believe you can configure the reader with a custom message lookup but the mechanism and capability differs by implementation.